# How does the coordinate system work in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and I've been told there are different coordinate systems: one for the model and another one for the application, but I'm not sure when should I use each one.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model's coordinate system is used when creating the different objects in a scene. The application's coordinate system is used to represent the entire scene. By multiplying the vertices of an object by the transformation matrix you are placing the object in the scene you want to represent, along with all the other objects.
I hope this answers your question.